# Firebase database rules: how to make field readonly?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to take to user ability to create some JSON data in my DB but restrict the ability to edit it in future. How should I write my rules?

```
"users": {
    // ".write": "auth != null",
    "$userUid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && $userUid === auth.uid",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make something read-only, simply don't grant write permission on it.

To make something create-only, only allow writing it if there's no existing data:

```
".write": "!data.exists()"
```

To then also make it so that the user can only write under their own node:

```
"$uid": {
  ".write": "!data.exists() && auth.uid === $uid"
}
```

To make something create-or-delete, allow writing a value when there's no data, nor writing no value when there is data:

```
".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()"
```